# On Taylor approximation in several variables

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I couldn't find a reference for this:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ $k$ times differentiable and $P_k$ its degree $k$ Taylor polynomial centered at $0$. Then, it is true that
$$f(x) = P_k(x) + o(\|x\|^k)?$$
where $\frac{o(\|x\|^k)}{\|x\|^k}\to0$ when $\|x\|\to0$. What is exactly the form of $P_k(x)$?

I could only find references for this, but when $f$ is $C^k$ and with real values.

Comment: This just requires one derivative, and your $P_k$ is the linear approximation which looks like $f(0)+Df(0)x$ where $Df$ is the Jacobian.

Comment: with $P_k$ i mean the Taylor polynomial of degree $k$

Comment: ahh ok, i see the mistake. I edited it

Comment: Then it is a rather ugly thing involving successively higher rank tensors. But the setup is very similar if you think of it in terms of bilinear, trilinear, etc. forms instead of tensors. The key point is that each term is a multilinear form all of whose arguments are $x$. This multilinear form spits out mixed derivatives by simply plugging in the coordinate vectors matching the derivatives.

Comment: but the approximation holds, right?

Comment: Yes, there is such a $P_k$.

Comment: I understand, thank you!